# How to hide html source code? Even when viewing source?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-devtools

I found this website https://samy.pl/ and even with my HTML knowledge I can't find the source of his site?

If you type "view-source:" before the website it should bring up the source but it doesn't?

He blocked most or all ways to inspect his source.

How is this possible?

Comment: It renders everything using Javascript. And it _pretends_ to load a `load.js` that doesn't do anything. But as you can see there's a meta refresh loading `/code`... so, take a look at `view-source:https://samy.pl/code/?ns=1`

Long story short, you can obfuscate HTML but never hide it from client because at the end the browser needs to render it.

Comment: If you want to see what all scripts the site uses (there are a bunch, including extjs and jquery), you can install Tampermonkey, add instant script injection at document-start, and write a userscript that overwrites `window.setInterval` so that the devtools check fails.

Comment: Open `chrome://inspect/#pages`, click "pause" after that site's entry, and when devtools opens press F5 to reload the page in paused mode where you can inspect DOM and scripts.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually see the sourcecode using Internet Explorer, or Safari with IE 11 set as useragent.

I'm not certain how he does it, but it is some kind of JavaScript that checks some flag in Chrome that tells him whether or not the inspector is open, and if true he removes the body and updates page so everything disappears.

Using IE and inspecting the source should give you the answer :)